# How to Load about 200 images in a single view in android?

Tags: android, imageview

Hello i want to make an application in which i have to load about 170 images i want images can move forward or back by user's finger touch means images can move left or right as user's on touch. Can you give me some ides or give any link so that i implement it in to my application
I had also surfed on internet but i can;t get the better solution for it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Then you should go with [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) widget and implement Asynchronous image loading feature for loading image asychronously as user touch left or right.

Comment: can you give any other solution rather than gallary because the images are fixed with each other and by one touch it can farward aroud 5 or 10 images on single touch. therefore i want another option

Answer (score 0):

you can use gallery with lazy Loading ...

Here is the Link for Lazy loading 
http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-list-view-in.html

Comment: But i don't want the listView i want the images can be viewed on full screen and user can move it by touch.

Comment: @user552027 you are writing like doing outsourcing of your project free-of cost.